# Why does heroku skip gems under development section in the gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems

I was having a application error so checked `heroku rails console`:

```
(master)$ heroku run rails console
Running rails console on morning-river-1349... up, run.8048
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'spring' (= 1.1.3) among 58 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0:/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:324:in `to_spec'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:64:in `gem'
    from /app/bin/spring:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/bin/rails:4:in `load'
    from /app/bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

**Solution**: I had to move the spring development section to the main in the gemfile.

Now the app works great but, 
any ideas on how to prevent heroku from skipping development category gems ? 

 **edit** : Sorry for the unnecessary trouble, I read the release notes of rails 4.1 {since then spring is preloaded}, hence including it in the gemfile was causing unnecessary problem, just removed it altogether.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heroku is your production environment, so Gems in your *development* and *test* groups in your Gemfile will never be installed on Heroku.

That is the whole point of [Groups in Bundler](http://bundler.io/v1.10/groups.html) - you don't need test or development related gems using up memory on your production server.

Spring is an application pre-loader to help speed up your development workflow, so you shouldn't have Spring installed in your production environment. Try to track down what is requiring Spring, and fix that problem first.

Comment: I understand that but, I was confused because when I was using the cloud 9 IDE the exact same code worked fine on heroku. But when I tried doing the same with my locally setup ubuntu dev environment it did not work. That had me thinking, anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: The Spring documentation explicitly says "You must not install Spring on your production environment." https://github.com/rails/spring#user-content-deployment

Have a Google of your error related to 'to_specs'. I think you should find something that helps your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some context, the problem isn't *heroku*, it's [bundler](http://bundler.io);

[image]

Bundler allows you to install gems specific to the environment in which you're working:

```
bundler install --without production staging test
```

This is handy for multiple types of dependencies (EG different web servers etc):

[image]